# Issues trying to boot Hirens BootCD on a HP with TPM and Bitlocker enabled

Tags: bitlocker, bootable-media, tpm, hiren

I am trying to boot [Hirens BootCD](https://www.hirensbootcd.org) on a HP with TPM and Bitlocker enabled. The boot will freeze after initializing the boot process. Secure boot is disabled. Neither secure boot nor without secure boot changes its behaviour. I am booting with [Ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html).

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hirens suggests using ISO2USB.  That is what I have always used without a problem.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Maybe figure out what you want to use Hirens for and then find an alternative to that.

Comment: This ^^^ is a good suggestion but Ventoy boots ISOs directly and everything I've tried so far (multiple Linux distros and different Windows 10 versions, often in the same stick) always worked flawlessly. I'm inclined to think you either have a corrupt ISO or Hiren's may not support your hardware due to not being updated for quite some time.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for all the good suggestions. I am going to explore and check all of them the coming days. Cheers

Comment: @Señor CMasMas:
worst program ever... pen drive ist not booting anymore at all. Bios is not finding anything either... hands off !

Comment: @seagull: 
good idea. Would you happen to have a suggestion? I have not been able to solve another general issue with Bitlocker and TPM 2.0 ... max security for my data but hard to access through Linux and else. But alternative to Hirens would be one step in the right direction, I guess